# AWS - import JSON file to load Dynamo table

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a json file that I want to use to load my Dynamo table in AWS.
In the AWS console, there is only an option to create one record at a time.  Not good: )

Essentially my .JSON  file is an array of objects which hold the data for each column in the table
ie:

```
{
    "Column1": "Column1 Value",
    "Column2": "Column2 Value",
    "Column3": "Column3 Value",
    "Column4": "Column4 Value",
  },
```

Is there any way to do this via AWS console and importing my json file, or do I have to use AWS JS SDK to programmatically do this ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to use the API. You could use the AWS-CLI instead, i.e:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name MusicCollection --item file://item.json --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

but you may need to tweak your JSON format a bit.

More examples and documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/put-item.html

Comment: Thank you! yep I had to tweak the json but it worked.

Comment: @29er Can you tell us how did you tweak the json? From the docs I understand that `item.json` file contains only one item. Did you get to load an **array of items** from one single `item.json` file? This is what the question is about, isn't it?

Comment: hi, yea, after I modiified the JSON, i used `aws dynamodb batch-write-item --table-name mytable --request-items file://TableItems.json`

Comment: just to clarify, we followed the instructions here :  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html

Comment: But what does your tweaked JSON look like, @29er?

Comment: @29er So what you're saying is that the answer to use "put-item" was incorrect?

Answer (score 18):

The answer from E.J. Brennan looks correct, for a single record, but it doesn't answer the original question (which needs to add an array of records).

For this, the [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.BatchOperations) is

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://aws-requests.json
```

But, you'll need to make a modified JSON file, like so (note the DynamoDB JSON that specifies data types):

```
{
    "YourTableName": [
        {   
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": { 
                    "Column1": { "S": "Column1 Value" },
                    "Column2": { "S": "Column2 Value" },
                    "Column3": { "S": "Column3 Value" },
                    "Column4": { "S": "Column4 Value" },
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": { 
                    "Column1": { "S": "Column1 Value" },
                    "Column2": { "S": "Column2 Value" },
                    "Column3": { "S": "Column3 Value" },
                    "Column4": { "S": "Column4 Value" },
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I see this solution allows up to 25 writes per batch-write-item request. This is probably important to let people know (I just tried it for 1600) :)

Answer (score 1):

I used boto3 in python to load the data

```
import boto3
import json

dynamodbclient=boto3.resource('dynamodb')
sample_table = dynamodbclient.Table('ec2metadata')

with open('/samplepath/spotec2interruptionevent.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

# parse file
obj = json.loads(data)

#instance_id and cluster_id is the Key in dynamodb table 

    response=sample_table.put_item(
                              Item={
                                  'instance_id': instanceId,
                                  'cluster_id': clusterId,
                                  'event':obj

                              }
                              )
```

Here is a sample for javascript:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Js.02.html#GettingStarted.Js.02.02

Answer (score 0):

The code above doesn't read in individual JSON objects, if you wanted to do that from a JSON file with multiple objects:

```
import boto3
import json

dynamodbclient=boto3.resource('dynamodb')
sample_table = dynamodbclient.Table('ec2metadata')

with open('/samplepath/spotec2interruptionevent.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

# parse file
objects = json.loads(data)

#instance_id and cluster_id is the Key in dynamodb table 

   for object in objects:
       instance_id = object["instance_id"]
       cluster_id =  object["cluster_id"]
       sample_table.put_item=(item=object)
```